# How to extract, in a list, all keys from a bucket in couchbase

Tags: couchbase, java

I am totally new in couchbase. I am using the java api and i want somehow to view all available keys in a bucket. Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mayer06, you might be right, but have in mind, that not all people are devs, that can grasp easy all the info.For example, i am a qa engineer.I use dev tools and i code, but due to my nature of my work, i cannot always go as deep, as you probably can.

Comment: Agreed, no problem there - but StackOverflow questions are supposed to show a little bit of effort on your part :)

Answer (score 11):

It is possible but you will need to create a view to do this (secondary index).

You can create a view in the couchbase webconsole like so:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(meta.type == "json") {
     emit(null);
  }
}
```

This will emit all the keys (keys are automatically emitted anyway so no need to include anything extra).

Then you can query the view like below using the java sdk. (Obviously you need to instantiate the couchbase client etc)

```java
View view = couchbaseClient.getView("DESIGN_VIEW NAME", "VIEW_NAME");
Query query = new Query();
ViewResponse viewResponse = couchbaseClient.query(view, query);

List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
for (ViewRow viewRow : viewResponse) {
   keys.add(viewRow.getKey());
}
```

Comment: is there a way without a VIEW?

Comment: Hi @BenoyPrakash this is the only way to access all keys within Couchbase.

Comment: Hey @stelios.p if this answered your question would you mind marking it as correct? Thanks!