# How to Use JQuery in Couchbase Mapreduce?

Tags: couchbase

Is there easy way to use custom Javascript library in Mapreduce in Couchbase? Something like this. I would like to get all keys for example.

```
function (doc, meta) {
   if(doc.doctype && doc.doctype=="regions"){
       var keys = jQuery.map( doc, function( value, key ) {
         return key;
       });
       emit(doc.id,keys)

   }
}
```

Comment: No, you cannot use JQuery. Also, even if you could use JQuery, what you are trying to do here makes no sense. It appears that you want to put a map function inside a map function. Even if this were possible, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question for how to retrieve all keys (just add the additional logic for your doctype)   [How to extract, in a list, all keys from a bucket in couchbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047635/how-to-extract-in-a-list-all-keys-from-a-bucket-in-couchbase)

As far as I know you can't use libraries such as Jquery with couchbase.